# What exactly is "personnel working"?

Tags: meaning, participle-phrases

Source: [Russia's middle class: We don't blame Putin](http://edition.cnn.com/2015/12/10/europe/russian-middle-class-putin/index.html?eref=edition)

Example:

> There's been a "renaissance" of engineers and **personnel working** for Russia's defense industry, he says, an elite class in the Soviet Union that fell apart in the chaos of the early post-Soviet period. Now they're back, and the Kremlin is paying attention. The group has almost nothing to do with the market economy, Lukyanov says, and they support Putin.

What exactly do they mean by *personnel working*?

Comment: I think the grouping is more *engineers and personnel* **working**, not *engineers and* **personnel working**, since **working** would be the verb. **Personnel** in this case would refer to non-engineering workers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning is similar to "[engineers and personnel] who work for ...". Note that the participle **working** refers not to **personnel** only, but to **engineers and personnel**. Let's rephrase:

> There's been a "renaissance" of **engineers and personnel who work** for Russia's defense industry, he says, an elite class in the Soviet Union that fell apart in the chaos of the early post-Soviet period. Now they're back, and the Kremlin is paying attention. The group has almost nothing to do with the market economy, Lukyanov says, and they support Putin.

Engineers and personnel of what kind? - Of the kind that works for the defense industry.

Following the dissolution of the USSR, there was a lack of funding, and these engineers and personnel suffered from low salaries and the necessity to look for other jobs. Now Putin's government is focused on restoring this sphere: manufacture of armaments, military vehicles, etc. Thus, these engineers and personnel **who work** for the defense industry undergo 'a renaissance'.

---

"Working for Russia's defense industry" is a present-participle phrase connected to "engineers and personnel". It is also called 'participial phrase'.

Comment: The problem is that the OP cannot parse the sentence correctly. He interprets "personnel working" as one thing instead of "personnel [and engineers]" + the verb "working".

Answer (score 0):

They mean the personnel are working for Russia's defense industry.  Just like the engineers are working for Russia's defense industry.